# Changing/shuffling text every 1.5 second in a react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and I wanted to do something a bit basic for my home screen of my application.

I would like to change the last text every 1.5 seconds in a given paragraph with the given array. Later on I will add some animation but for right now I just wanted to do the basics.

In my react component, I have something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    let textArray = ['eat', 'sleep', 'drink', 'snore', 'foo', 'buzz', 'whatever'];
    let textThatChanges;

    for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
      textThatChanges = textArray[i];
    }

    return (
      <section>
        <h1>Hello, my name is Barry Allen</h1>
        <p>I like to <span> {textThatChanges}</span></p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

In plain jquery it would look like something below:

```js
textShuffle = function(element, text, timer){
  var thisEl = document.getElementById(element),
    counter = 0,
    t = setInterval(function(){  
        if(counter == text.length -1){
            t = window.clearInterval(t);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            //change markup to next the next string
            thisEl.innerHTML = text[counter];
            counter++;      
        },310);
    }, timer);
  }
  
  
  
var shuffle1 = new textShuffle('foo', 
                               ['eat', 'sleep', 'drink', 'snore', 'foo', 'buzz', 'whatever'],
                               1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  I like to <span id='foo'>Play</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

const textArray = ['eat', 'sleep', 'drink', 'snore', 'foo', 'buzz', 'whatever'];

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { textIdx: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
      let currentIdx = this.state.textIdx;
      this.setState({ textIdx: currentIdx + 1 });
    }, 1500);
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeout);
  }

  render() {
    let textThatChanges = textArray[this.state.textIdx % textArray.length];

    return (
      <section>
        <h1>Hello, my name is Barry Allen</h1>
        <p>I like to <span>{textThatChanges}</span></p>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){ 
        //setup your timer here.
        //in your timer, call setState on this
        //something like this.setState({textThatChanges:YourText});
  }
  render() { 

    return (
      <section>
        <h1>Hello, my name is Barry Allen</h1>
        <p>I like to <span> {this.state.textThatChanges}</span></p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```