# How to change state every x seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change the name of every avatar every X seconds, I have follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094060/changing-shuffling-text-every-1-5-second-in-a-react-component/42096287) and it works fine but, right now its changing all the names to the same name from **RandomAcidName** array.

I imagine that I need to iterate through this list also, so each name is passing just once to every avatar.

Here is my code

**nameJuggler** is passing the name to each avatar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Avatar.scss";
import AcidData from "../Acidsdata/Acids-data.json";
import RandomAcidName from "../../../src/randomAcidName.json";

const getDate = new Date();
const getDay = getDate.getDate();
const getMonth = getDate.getMonth() + 1;
const fullTodayDate = getDay + "/" + getMonth;

const AvatarDisplay = props => {
  return (
    <div key={props.id} className="container__position-relative">
      <img src={props.photo} alt={props.name} className="avatar__img" />
      <div className="container__position-absolute avatar__name">
        <span>{props.name}</span>
      </div>
      {props.cumple}
    </div>
  );
};

class AcidPoblation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sudoNameId: 0,
      acidos: AcidData,
      randomName: RandomAcidName
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeName = setInterval(() => {
      let currentSudoNameId = this.state.sudoNameId;

      this.setState({
        sudoNameId: currentSudoNameId + 1
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.changeName);
  }

  render() {
    let nameJuggler =
      RandomAcidName[this.state.sudoNameId % RandomAcidName.length];

    return (
      <main className="container__grid">
        {this.state.acidos.map(item => (
          <AvatarDisplay
            photo={item.acidphoto}
            name={nameJuggler}
            birth={item.birthdate}
            id={item.acidid}
            cumple={
              item.birthdate === fullTodayDate ? (
                <img
                  src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x40"
                  alt="feliz cumpleaños"
                  className="container__position-absolute avatar__birth-date"
                />
              ) : null
            }
          />
        ))}
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default AcidPoblation;
```

Here is the Json with the names

```
[

  "Anderson",
  "Ashwoon",
  "Aikin",
  "Bateman",
  "Bongard",
  "Bowers",
  "Boyd",
  "Cannon",
  "Cast",
  "Deitz",
  "Dewalt",
  "Ebner",
  "Frick",
  "Hancock",
  "Haworth",
  "Hesch",
  "Hoffman",
  "Kassing",
  "Knutson",
  "Lawless",
  "Lawicki",
  "Mccord",
  "McCormack",
  "Miller",
  "Myers",
  "Nugent",
  "Ortiz",
  "Orwig",
  "Ory",
  "Paiser",
  "Pak",
  "Pettigrew",
  "Quinn",
  "Quizoz",
  "Ramachandran",
  "Resnick",
  "Sagar",
  "Schickowski",
  "Schiebel",
  "Sellon",
  "Severson",
  "Shaffer",
  "Solberg",
  "Soloman",
  "Sonderling",
  "Soukup",
  "Soulis",
  "Stahl",
  "Sweeney",
  "Tandy",
  "Trebil",
  "Trusela",
  "Trussel",
  "Turco",
  "Uddin",
  "Uflan",
  "Ulrich",
  "Upson",
  "Vader",
  "Vail",
  "Valente",
  "Van Zandt",
  "Vanderpoel",
  "Ventotla",
  "Vogal",
  "Wagle",
  "Wagner",
  "Wakefield",
  "Weinstein",
  "Weiss",
  "Woo",
  "Yang",
  "Yates",
  "Yocum",
  "Zeaser",
  "Zeller",
  "Ziegler",
  "Bauer",
  "Baxster",
  "Casal",
  "Cataldi",
  "Caswell",
  "Celedon",
  "Chambers",
  "Chapman",
  "Christensen",
  "Darnell",
  "Davidson",
  "Davis",
  "DeLorenzo",
  "Dinkins",
  "Doran",
  "Dugelman",
  "Dugan",
  "Duffman",
  "Eastman",
  "Ferro",
  "Ferry",
  "Fletcher",
  "Fietzer",
  "Hylan",
  "Hydinger",
  "Illingsworth",
  "Ingram",
  "Irwin",
  "Jagtap",
  "Jenson",
  "Johnson",
  "Johnsen",
  "Jones",
  "Jurgenson",
  "Kalleg",
  "Kaskel",
  "Keller",
  "Leisinger",
  "LePage",
  "Lewis",
  "Linde",
  "Lulloff",
  "Maki",
  "Martin",
  "McGinnis",
  "Mills",
  "Moody",
  "Moore",
  "Napier",
  "Nelson",
  "Norquist",
  "Nuttle",
  "Olson",
  "Ostrander",
  "Reamer",
  "Reardon",
  "Reyes",
  "Rice",
  "Ripka",
  "Roberts",
  "Rogers",
  "Root",
  "Sandstrom",
  "Sawyer",
  "Schlicht",
  "Schmitt",
  "Schwager",
  "Schutz",
  "Schuster",
  "Tapia",
  "Thompson",
  "Tiernan",
  "Tisler"

]
```

I need that every name is assing just once.

[In this link](https://repl.it/@rezpo/nameJuggler) is a replica of my project...

Comment: What is the current output? Also, can you reproduce this in Codesandbox for someone to play around?

Comment: You could fix this a few ways. One option is to alter the randomAcidName.json to be `module.exports = [` instead of just `[`. thus exporting the array. Then, instead of import in your JS file, you could say `const RandomAcidName = require("../../../src/randomAcidName.json");` instead of the `import RandomAcidName ...` line

Comment: @daydreamer [In this link](https://repl.it/@rezpo/nameJuggler) is a replica of my project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
let nameJuggler = [this.state.sudoNameId % RandomAcidName.length];
```

this.state.sudoNameId won't be unique because it's just a number set in the parent component and will be provided to all of the AvatarDisplays not dynamically changing.
An easy fix would just make the .map also have an index so you can add the index to the this.state.sudoNameId which will make each number unique.
See code below

```js
    return (
      <main className="container__grid">
        {this.state.acidos.map((item, index) => {
            let nameJuggler =
            RandomAcidName[(this.state.sudoNameId + index) % RandomAcidName.length];
          return (
          <AvatarDisplay
            photo={item.acidphoto}
            name={nameJuggler}
            birth={item.birthdate}
            id={item.acidid}
            cumple={
              item.birthdate === fullTodayDate ? (
                <img
                  src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x40"
                  alt="feliz cumpleaños"
                  className="container__position-absolute avatar__birth-date"
                />
              ) : null
            }
          />
        )
        })}
      </main>
```